# I tried mongoose find, why is [ ] being printed?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I tried to output the information stored in the db, but the result is only []. Where is the problem?

route/serch.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var crodata = require('../model/cro');

router.get('/',function (req,res,next) {

    
        var ser = req.query.word;  //namsan
        crodata.find({tags:{$regex:ser}} , function(err, result) {
            if(err) { console.log(err)}
            console.log(result);
        }) 
        //res.render('serch',result)      
});


module.exports = router;
```

/model/cro.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var croSchema = new Schema(
    { index:String,content:String,data:String,like:String,place:String,tags:String}
)


module.exports = mongoose.model('cro1',croSchema);
```

Information stored in db

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5fe916d69d46ee5848393949"},
"index":"1",
"content":"Seoul Vibes.#namsan #fstopgear #breathbaselayer ",
"data":"2020-12-27",
"like":"946",
"place":"Seoul",
"tags":"['#namsan', '#nseoultower',]"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that `req.query.word` property has a value, remember that `req.query` shape is based on user-controlled input (should be validated before trusting).

Beside that, you query look ok, but is good to know that, MongoDB must perform a collection scan, i.e. scan every document in a collection, to select those documents that match you query statement.

More about [Regex and Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use)

Comment: `req.query.word` has a value. But in mongoose
As a result of using Adventure.countDocuments() , it came out with 0 data. Maybe the db connection is the problem.